# Add libraries to PYTHONPATH In Pycharm (Windows 10)

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda

When setting up a Pycharm development environment, I am trying to follow the following instruction, which is for Linux environment. However, my system is virtual environment created by Anaconda, running on Windows 10. How to add Pythonpath in Pycharm with respect to this kind of environment?

```
Add Libraries to PYTHONPATH
    When running locally, the tensorflow/models/research/ and slim directories should be appended to PYTHONPATH. 
    This can be done by running the following from tensorflow/models/research/:



# From tensorflow/models/research/
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
Note: This command needs to run from every new terminal you start.
```

Comment: set `PYTHONPATH` system environment variable https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10

Answer (score 1):

You may follow the following steps:

1. Get the Python executable path for Anaconda:
   Go to window's "programs" and search for "Anaconda Command line" then right click on the properties and copy the path then go to the cmd terminal and type the path and then type python.exe at the end till you logged in the python interpreter. This may vary from an OS to another but this works for me under windows 7.
2. In Pycharm: Add a new Python interpreter by following exactly the instructions listed in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html.
   Use the Anaconda python executable path you got in step1 for the new interpreter called "Conda" for example. Set the new project to use "Conda" interpreter instead of the normal default Python interpreter.
3. Apply the new changes and restart Pycharm. Open the Settings/Preferences dialog box, and click Project Interpreter page to make sure that the project is pointing to "Conda" interpreter.

Hope this will help!